# jQuery .each() method doesn't iterate over all images

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to make an image carousel. I am using the jQuery .each() method to iterate over all the images in the div with class="slideshow".

HTML code

```
<div class="slideshow">
  <img src="images/page-1-hero-image.jpg" alt="school's image" class="img-responsive page-one-pic mySlides">
  <img src="images/Capture2.PNG" alt="school pic" class="img-responsive mySlides">
  <img src="images/Capture.PNG" alt="school pic" class="img-responsive mySlides">
  <img src="images/Capture3.PNG" alt="school pic" class="img-responsive mySlides">
</div>
```

CSS code

```
.mySlides {
    display: none;
    position: fixed;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    z-index: 1;
    /* to make pic responsive */
    min-height: 100%;
    min-width: 1024px;
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
}
```

Javascript:

```
function carousel() {
    $(".slideshow > img").each(function(index, element) {
        $(element).fadeIn(1000).delay(2000);
        setTimeout(carousel, 1000);
    });
}
```

The function only fades in the first image and then stops. The other images are not displayed.

here is the link to the hosted project:
https://rimildeyjsr.github.io/St.Anthony-Website/

Comment: What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: With this JS code you'll kill your browser :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just an improvement to the previous answer, you can do it in the form of a callback(which ensures you that the function is called only after the `fadeIn` has occurred or happened, so you wont need a `setTimeout`) as follows

```
function carousel() {
    var imgs = $(".slideshow > img");
    imgs.each(function(index, element) {   
        $(element).delay(index * 2000).fadeIn(1000, function() {
            if (index + 1 >= imgs.length) {
                carousel(); // call the function only after all images are fadeIn completed
            }
        });
    });
}
```

See if that helps and if not drop a comment below

**Edit**:

After `.fadeIn()` does it's job, it sets the `display` value to `block` what you have to do here is, hide the elements before continuing the slideshow animation, for simplicity we'll set all the `img` elements display to hidden by using `.hide(0)`. This sets the elements `display` to `none`

```
function carousel() {
    var imgs = $(".slideshow > img");
    imgs.stop().hide(0); // hide all the images whenever the carousel() is called
    imgs.each(function(index, element) {   
        $(element).delay(index * 2000).fadeIn(1000, function() {
            if (index + 1 >= imgs.length) {
                carousel(); // call the function only after all images are fadeIn completed
            }
        });
    });
}
```

Let me know if you need anything else

Comment: the images are fading in and out perfectly, but they aren't looping back to the first picture.I added a console.log to check the execution, it is executing, but the slideshow is not working

Comment: check the edit @RimilDey, see if that solves the issue

Comment: I made the first image just show because of the ugly white transistion it was having, but apart from that it worked. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 3):

This code:

```
function carousel() {
    $(".slideshow > img").each(function(index,element){
        $(element).fadeIn(1000).delay(2000);
        setTimeout(carousel,1000);
    });
}
```

Says: "For each img element, spend a second fading in, then delay by two seconds before doing nothing, and reschedule this entire process (not per element, for all of them) to run again a second from now."

That doesn't make much sense, you'll be calling `carousel` several times again roughly at the time the first image finishes fading out.

Given the term "slideshow" I'd guess what you're trying to do is show each image for two seconds before spending a second having the next one fade in, looping when you get to the end. If so, you want to call `carousel` *once*, two seconds after the last image has finished fading in. You can do that by delaying the fades and the next call.

```
function carousel() {
    var imgs = $(".slideshow > img");
    imgs.each(function(index,element){
        // Don't make the first one (index = 0) wait at all;
        // make the second (index = 1) wait 3 seconds, the third
        // (index = 2) wait 6 seconds, etc. And then fade in
        $(element).delay(index * 3000).fadeIn(1000);
    });
    // Start the entire process again two seconds after the last image fades in
    setTimeout(carousel, imgs.length * 3000);
}
```

Comment: @t-j-crowder: the images are fading perfectly, but they arent looking back. As in, after the last picture,it doesnt go back to the first. I added a console.log in the beginning of the function, to check if the function is executing, and it seems that it is, but the images aint looping.

Comment: Thank you for your explanation, it couldn't have been better :)